How to smooth a cubic B-spline given a list of control points that make it?
I am trying to smooth a hand drawn curve which is represented as a list of control points of uniform cubic B-spline. Since it is hand drawn it has little noise (niggles) which I would like to smoothen.
I am able to interpolate the control points to generate the points on the curve. But I don't know if I smooth that how to recover the equivalent in new control points.
Is it possible to smooth the original set of control points on the Bézier curve?

This is one of those "you really need to show your [mcve], as well as example input and desired output based on that input" situations, because what you want to do and what you're asking about may not be the same thing, and you definitely want the "what you want to do" part solved (e.g. you don't want to ask an [XY question}(https://xyproblem.info/)).

What about using the RDP algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to smooth the original points and then interpolate that?

You could smooth the input polyline of control points by projecting a control point onto the connection line between its two neighbors (how far you move it from its original point to its projection correlates with the smoothing amount). Iterate a couple of times until you are happy with the result. This can be seen as a form of Laplacian smoothing.
